# How to create floating 'boxes' inside a column-like div - Daily schedule application

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a daily schedule application, which shows hours from 6:00 to 22:00 and boxes which represent time-slots (tasks to be done). The box position represents the tasks time - so a box at the 14:00 mark (visually) represents a task that begins at 14:00.
The duration is represented by the boxes length (height-wise). If the above box ends at 15:00, the duration is 1 hour.

I have created a div which is column-like (see picture below) and want to fill it with boxes, each box represents a task.
lets say I already have a task in the database for that day, and just want to load it (i.e. to create a nested div inside the column-div to represent that task).

**The question is - How do I place the task at the right position inside the column-div, regarding it's time and duration (which I know). It should be done relatively to the column-divs length.**

I don't want to use absolute position because I want everything to resize dynamically - if the window is full-size or smaller, the height position and length should vary for both column-div and nested divs.

I have a basic template which creates a column of hours and a visual div which is the same height.
link to a demo image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYRzV.jpg

expected result should be a box-like div inside the column div, starting at the right time (lets say 14:00 as per the example above) and ends at the 15:00 hour mark.

I just want to add that I have thought of how to calculate the task-div's length (height-wise) in percentage of the whole coulmn-div's height. It is duration/16 * 100 (because of the 16 hours in the schedule from 6 to 22)
What I need to know is how to position it vertically inside the column-div.

Code:
runs in django (python)

html (the relevant part):

```
    <div id="schedule-div">
            <div id="table-div">
                <table id='schedule-table'>
                    <th>Hour</th>
                    {% for n in hours %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ n }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tasks-div"></div>
        </div>
```

css (relevant part):

```
#schedule-div {
    display: flex;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#tasks-div {
    background-color: #606060;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    flex: 1;
}

#schedule-table {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    border-collapse: collapse;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Write short sample code so that we can help you.

Comment: Hey, 
I haven't tried anything practically because I had no idea how to even approach this.
I have looked at flexbox but didn't see a way to position divs relative to the parent div

Comment: There is the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property for flexbox.

Comment: Hey, thanks but it does not fit my problem because, to my understanding, it requires the flex elements to be adjacent. And in my case, there can be only one task for example - and it needs to be in a specific position, relative to its hour (lets say 14:00). So the order, to my understanding, does not solve this problem.